How can I query a non-namespaced custom object in a dev org that shares the same name as a managed package object?
I have a managed package that includes a custom object called Action__c. The package also includes an Apex class that uses a dynamic query to fetch records. The Apex function takes two parameters: the object name and the list of fields. It queries records dynamically using Database.query.
Here’s the issue:
I installed the managed package into a dev org that also has a custom object named Action__c (not namespaced). When running the Apex class from the managed package, it always queries the Action__c object from the managed package (with the namespace), even if I pass the dev org's Action__c (non-namespaced) as the object name.
List<String> fields = new List<String>{'Title__c'};
List<SObject> records = DynamicQueryExample.queryRecords('Action__c', fields);

public class DynamicQueryExample {
  public static List<SObject> queryRecords(String objectName, List<String> fieldList) {
    // Construct the field string for the SOQL query
    String fields = String.join(', ', fieldList);

    // Construct the dynamic SOQL query
    String query = 'SELECT ' + fields + ' FROM ' + objectName;

    // Execute the query using Database.query
    List<SObject> records = Database.query(query);

    return records;
  }
}

When executing this code, I encounter the following error message:
No such column 'Title__c' on entity 'namespace__Action__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
How can I ensure that the query fetches records from the dev org's Action__c (non-namespaced) instead of the namespaced one from the managed package?

This question might help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133959/sobjecttype-name-conflict-in-queries/133964#133964. It might be a good idea to upvote this as well https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh9rUAB/support-dynamic-soql-no-shadowing-option

Fundamentally it is impossible for your managed code to query subscriber object records or subscriber fields that have the same name as packaged objects or their fields. You would have to delegate the query to subscriber code to do this.

Unlikely useful in your case, and untested: If the object has a lookup, and the parent is known, maybe it's possible to make use of subqueries?! Like in SELECT (SELECT Id FROM AssetActions) FROM Asset, and then work with List and do the remaining filtering based on SObject.get() in Apex?!
